# FindControl throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Within my ASP gridview, I have the following (updated to show full gridview):

```
<asp:GridView ID="TPAnnuity_GridView" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" Runat="server"
    DataSourceID="TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="AnnuityTotalPointsID" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" PageSize="20">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="CompanyName" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="EditACompanyID" runat="server" DataSource="<%# ddlCompanyDS %>" DataValueField="CompanyID" DataTextField="CompanyName" selectedValue='<%# Bind("CompanyID") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="NewCompanyID" runat="server" DataSource="<%# ddlCompanyDS %>" DataValueField="CompanyID" DataTextField="CompanyName"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewCompanyID" Display="Dynamic"  ForeColor="" ErrorMessage="You must enter a value. *" Enabled="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </FooterTemplate>
        <FooterStyle Wrap="False" />
    </asp:TemplateField>    
</Columns>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <br />
    <i>No Commission Data to display.</i>
    <br />
    <br />
</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

And within my back end, I have the following:

```
Sub TPAnnuity_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles TPAnnuity_GridView.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Cancel" Then
        'Reset Footer Row input fields
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewCompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0

    ElseIf e.CommandName = "Insert" Then
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Clear()
        Dim test1 As New Parameter("CompanyIDInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        test1.DefaultValue = CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewCompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test1)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.Insert()

    ElseIf e.CommandName = "Update" Then
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Clear()
        Dim param1 As New Parameter("CompanyIDInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        param1.DefaultValue = CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("EditACompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedValue ****THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE****
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param1)        
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.Update()
    End If
End Sub
```

The `Cancel` and `Insert` functions work just fine, operating off of the footer. Every time hit the "Update" button, I get a NullReferenceException on the `param1.Default Value =` line.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on here?

Comment: because you are using TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow. to find control while updating....thats why you are getting issue. While Updating you have to use GridView Edit Rows not footer

Comment: @Piyush Any clue what my syntax there would be? `CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.Rows.FindControl("EditACompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedValue` throws more errors.

Comment: can you show me .aspx code for gridview.  I think you have to get row using this   Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index), then get value for "EditACompanyID"

Comment: @Piyush I've updated the OP to show the gridview.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I've looked at that, and I understand what it means, but it's not helping me fix it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your row should look like this:

```
param1.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditACompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
```

Instead of utilizing the FooterRow, you have to use the source row. Since you passed that in with `e`, you can use this.

Comment: AHHHHH glorious. Thank you so much.